# Sharing a link in facebook

Tags: angularjs, socialshare

I am sharing a link `http://35.154.102.35/index.html#/shareProfile`in facebook. But sharing doesnt happen , it take shareProfile as userid and redirect to profile of person share.profile.What can be done to redirect to my link ?

HtmL:

```
 <div class="share-links">
      <a href="http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{shareVDetails}}" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.shareVDetails = "http://35.154.102.35/index.html#/shareProfile";
```

Comment: Try using ng-href instead in the link maybe?

Comment: I tried using ng-href also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$scope.shareVDetails = "http://35.154.102.35/index.html#/shareProfile";

$scope.facebook = "http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + $scope.shareVDetails;
```

on html

```
<a href="{{ facebook }}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to use ng-href for links if you're using data in a controller as part of the link as per their doc.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode url, because the hash sign is treated like it is part of facebook link not yours. So:

```
$scope.shareVDetails = encodeURIComponent("http://35.154.102.35/index.html#/shareProfile");
```